# awk to search two strings and sort the desired column

Tags: linux, awk

I'm Just looking forward to print out the column sixth while filtering for the two different string.

### Below is the sample raw data

```
06-Jun-2019 11:21:28.437 queries: info: client 192.168.20.11#44622: query: fulker-pulp-east.platform9.net IN A + (00.00.00.00)
06-Jun-2019 11:21:36.310 queries: info: client 192.168.20.13#43274: query: fulker-pulp-east.platform9.net IN A + (00.00.00.00)
```

### What tried as follows:

```
awk '/Jun-2019/ && /queries: info: client/{print $6}' /var/named/chroot/var/log/bind.log  | cut -d"#" -f1 | sort -u
```

Above works but but another `cut` and `sort`.

### Desired:

How could above be achieved with awk only one liner, appreciate any help.

Comment: further shortened with cut removed:  `awk -vFS="[# ]" '/Jun-2019/ && /queries: info: client/{print $6}' /var/named/chroot/var/log/bind.log |sort -u`

Comment: @PS.     thanks for the hint.

Comment: This might work: `awk -vFS="[# ]" '/Jun-2019/ && /queries: info: client/ && !n[$6]++ && $0=$6' /var/named/chroot/var/log/bind.log`

Comment: @Cyrus, thanks for  the another trick.